# How to sum values from one column based on specific conditions from other column in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(plot = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
                 species = c("Fagus","Fagus","Quercus","Picea", "Abies","Fagus","Fagus","Quercus","Picea", "Abies","Fagus","Fagus","Quercus","Picea", "Abies"),
                 value =  sample(100, size = 15, replace = TRUE)) 

head(df)
  plot species value
1    A   Fagus    53
2    A   Fagus    48
3    A Quercus     5
4    A   Picea    25
5    A   Abies    12
6    B   Fagus    12
```

Now, I want to create a new data frame containing per `plot` values for `share.conifers` and `share.broadleaves` by basically summing the `values` with conditions applied for `species`. I thought about using `case_when` but I am not sure how to write the syntax:

```
df1 <- df %>% share.broadleaves = case_when(plot = plot & species = "Fagus" or species = "Quercus" ~ FUN="sum")

df1 <- df %>% share.conifers = case_when(plot = plot & species = "Abies" or species = "Picea" ~ FUN="sum")
```

I know this is not right, but I would like something like this.

Comment: Could you provide the desired outcome please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`/`tidyr`:

First construct the group, do the calculation and then spread into columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(type = case_when(species %in% c("Fagus", "Quercus") ~ "broadleaves",
                          species %in% c("Abies", "Picea") ~ "conifers")) |>
  group_by(plot, type) |>
  summarise(share = sum(value)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  pivot_wider(values_from = "share", names_from = "type", names_prefix = "share.")
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  plot  share.broadleaves share.conifers
  <chr>             <int>          <int>
1 A                   159             77
2 B                    53             42
3 C                   204             63
```

I am not sure if you want to sum or get the share, but the code could easily be adapted to whatever goal you have.

Answer (score 0):

One way could just be summarizing by `plot` and `species`:

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  group_by(plot, species) |>
  summarize(share = sum(value))
```

If you really want to get the share of a specific species per plot you could also do:

```
df |>
  group_by(plot) |>
  summarize(share_certain_species = sum(value[species %in% c("Fagus", "Quercus")]) / sum(value))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  plot  share_certain_species
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 A                     0.546
2 B                     0.583
3 C                     0.480
```

Comment: Yeah, I could use ```agregate``` for that but it does not give me what I want. So I thought to create another classifcation first based on species, and then agregate based on that classification. Not the quickest, but it will get the job done.

Comment: Not sure what to make of this comment. The code above does exactly what you asked for. If that's not what you want, please clarify and also share an example of your expected outcome.

Comment: I want to sum ```values``` not for each specific observation in ```species``` but I want something like this ```share.broadleaves <- if species == "Fagus" or "Quercus" sum values```

Comment: And you want to return a df with JUST these species, or basically the original data frame where for these species you have the sum and for all otehr species you have a missing?